# Any button on page sends form, even ones outside of form tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, button

I have a form with two buttons; calculate(submit) & reset. I want the calculate button to send the form(php) and call some javascript, but i want the reset button to only call some javascript. however at the moment, both buttons send the form regardless of where they're placed on the page.

```
<form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
    <input type="text" name="business" id="business" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
    <button onclick="calculate();">Calculate</button>
</form>
<button onclick="reset();">Reset</button>
```

Comment: I think all you really need to do is have your `onclick` cancel the default action of the button so it won't submit. I think in jQuery it's called `.preventDefault()`

Comment: Benhamin Poignant has a simple solution...no need for extra js bits!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need set type property, by default it s "submit" button just add `type="button"`